# ¿Por qué no toma el RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter, null

tengo el siguiente código para adaptar una lista de personas a un RecyclerView

```
private void showProspectsInAdapter(List<Prospect>prospects){
        adapterProspectsList = new AdapterProspectsList(this,this,prospects);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerViewProspects.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerViewProspects.setAdapter(adapterProspectsList);

    }
```

En el onCreate llamo un método que le asigna el RecyclerView a una variable

```
 loadViews();

private void loadViews(){
        recyclerViewProspects = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_prospects);
    }
```

cuando la aplicación llega al primer código que mostré, tiene un error

```
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0):

En este caso solo debes asegurar llamar llamar el método

```
private void loadViews(){
        recyclerViewProspects = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_prospects);
    }
```

Antes de llamar el método `showProspectsInAdapter()` que es donde asignas el Layout a tu `RecyclerView`:

```
private void showProspectsInAdapter(List<Prospect>prospects){
        adapterProspectsList = new AdapterProspectsList(this,this,prospects);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerViewProspects.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerViewProspects.setAdapter(adapterProspectsList);

    }
```

Si lo anterior es correcto entonces también debes asegurar tener el `RecyclerView` con id `recyclerView_prospects` dentro del Layout que carga tu `Activity`.